# Push Notification After App Was Updated

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Well, I know android device registration_id -s are changed upon application version update. So, once I update app on play store and users' devices update (automatically) the app to the new version, **how can I push notifications to their devices?** - Because between that interval (app was updated, but never opened after update) device needs to be re-registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your application is updated, the system sends out two broadcasts: [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) (sent only to your application, available in API 12 (3.1) or higher) and [ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) (sent to every app, check `getData()` on the Intent to get the package name, available on all API levels).

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` that listens for the broadcast and starts a service which would then re-register with GCM as suggested by [PushBullet's blog of reliable GCM](https://blog.pushbullet.com/2014/02/12/keeping-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-working-reliably-techincal-post/).

I'd strongly recommend disabling any receiver listening for `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast on Android 3.1+ devices as otherwise your receiver/process will get triggered on other apps as well (in that case, you'd want two receivers: one for <3.1, one for >=3.1 and use `android:enabled` with boolean resources to disable them appropriately based on API level).